# Как построить несколько чатов на сокетах?

Tags: php, websocket

Всем привет! Появилась задача, построить структуру личных сообщений (диалоги + конференции) на сокетах. Вернее то что уже есть перевести на сокеты.

Сейчас проект ещё только набирает обороты, но уже появляются проблемы с большим количеством AJAX-запросов, которые приходится повторять раз в 8 секунд (проверка новых сообщений) с каждого активного пользователя.

Знаю, что необходимо использовать сокеты, но как это сделать для нескольких чатов/диалогов одновременно?

Структура подобна современным месседжерам. Слева панель с последними диалогами, справа сообщения. При выборе диалога, подгружаются последние сообщения.
Если появляются новые сообщения в любом из диалогов он помещается наверх и пишется кол-во новых сообщений (аля ВК).

Все сообщения и диалоги хранится в БД (MySQL). Бэкэнд - Laravel 5.

Самое главное: хотелось бы обойтись only PHP, без ноды.

Помогите, люди добрые! Спасибо! :)

P.S.: Присматриваюсь к https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php но как заюзать пока не пойму..

Comment: Как то дохло этот Textalk выглядит. Последний коммит 2 года назад. Ratchet PHP самый развитый Websocket сервер для PHP, на сколько я знаю http://socketo.me

Comment: сейчас юзаю https://github.com/Devristo/phpws пока полет нормальный.